# Get all Foreign Keys of a Foreign Key in Django

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

For example,

If there was a model `Bookshelf` which had a foreign key to a model `Books` that was accesible by `bookshelf.books`, and the Book model has a foreign key `Author` (accesible through `book.authors`), how would I get all the authors from a Bookshelf?

Example models.py

```py
class Bookshelf(models.Model):
    pass

class Book(models.Model):
    bookshelf = models.ForeignKey(Bookshelf, related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Author(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='authors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I could do:

```py
author_qs = QuerySet(Author)
for book in my_bookshelf.books.all():
    author_qs |= book.authors.all()
```

But I doubt this is very efficient.

Any help is much appreciated.  (If it matters, I'm using Postgres)

Comment: Can you add `models.py`

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane Added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*To span a relationship, use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.*" - [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

So you can do:

```
queryset = Author.objects.filter(book__bookshelf=bookshelf)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  Would it be slightly more efficient to do `.filter(book__bookshelf__pk=bookshelf.pk)`?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a solution can be found in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37515546/14349691

The above answer is also very detailed.